# Unicode math and subscript spacing

Tags: unicode-math, subscripts, superscripts, stix

The following code results in the 'j' being too far away from the parenthesis:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\let\arrowvert\undefined
\RequirePackage[stix2]{newtxmath}
\let\openbox\undefined
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{stix2}{b}{n}

\newcommand{\p}[1]{\left({{}{#1}}_{{}}\,\negthickspace\right)}

\title{Untitled}
\date{Typeset on \today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

$$ D_{v_p} = \p{ {\widehat e}_i }_{j} $$

\end{document}
```

Upon commenting the STIX-related code, the problem seems to disappear. Replacing it with `\usepackage{unicode-math}` produces the same artifact.

What is wrong?

Comment: What's your use case for wanting to using `\left(` and `\right)`? to encase `\hat{e}_i` (or `\widehat{e}_i`)? Put differently, why not write `(\widehat{e}_i)_j` or, if you prefer,  `{(\widehat{e}_i)}_j`-- and obtain nicely spaced subscripts?

Comment: @Mico, this does not seem like an extremely general solution.

Comment: "Extremely general solutions" are usually not *optimal* solutions. Hence my question: What's your use case for deliberately generating parentheses that can be much too large for the job and can generate all kinds of odd, but utterly avoidable, follow-up problems?

Comment: @Mico, I hoped there is a simpler way.

Comment: @MikeLand You triggered a LuaTeX bug here, but that only applies to legacy math fonts, so it does not happen with `unicode-math`. So it's impossible to say why your attempt with unicode-math didn't work without seeing the code. Currently the `unicode-math` tag and title are a bit misleading since the question is mostly about what happens with legacy math.